# How can I control execution of a SQL statement based on the DB2s structure?

Tags: sql, if-statement, db2, db2-luw

We want to run a simple SQL statement (dropping and creating an index), but only if the old index has not already been deleted. After looking up the syntax for [IF in DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_ifstatement4nativesqlpl.html), I came up with this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT indname FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES WHERE INDNAME = 'TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD') 
THEN 
    DROP INDEX TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD;
    create index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_NEW on example_table
    (
        id,
        another_field
    );
END IF;
```

When run with either SQuirrel (already setup to run with db2) or via command line, this script results in an error:

> An unexpected token "IF EXISTS (SELECT indname FROM SYSCAT.INDEX" was
>   found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include: 
>   "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.23.42 SQL Code:
>   -104, SQL State: 42601

So - what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something, or is there another way to achieve my goal (check for $thing in database, execute appropriate query) that so far has not occured to me?

Comment: What’s your Db2 version and platform?

Comment: DB2 v11.1.2020, Win7

Answer (score 0):

If `IF` statement is valid only in a compound-SQL block (i.e. inside a stored-procedure/routine/function/anonymous-block).

It's not valid standalone as your question shows, and that is why Db2 throws the -104 error.

You can look up the explanation of the sqlcode -104 by looking up SQL0104N in the free online Db2 Knowledge Center at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0104n).

To be able to use compound-SQL in your Squirrel-SQL tool, you need to configure squirrel to use an alternative statement terminator. Google that. In the examples below, I show a statement terminator of @ (to delimit the block).

Here are two different ways to do what you want with Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows, each uses an anonymous block. Other approaches are possible.

In this example the drop-index will only run if the index-name exists in the current schema:

`begin
   declare v_index_exists integer default 0;
   select 1 into v_index_exists
   from syscat.indexes
   where indname = 'TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD';
   if  v_index_exists = 1
   then
       execute immediate('drop index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD');
       execute immediate('create index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_NEW on example_table ( id, another_field)');
   end if;
end@`

In this example the drop-index will always run, but the block won't abort if the index does'nt exist (i.e. it will continue and not throw any error).

`begin
   declare v_no_such_index integer default 0;
   declare not_exists condition for sqlstate '42704';
   declare continue handler for not_exists set v_no_such_index=1;
   execute immediate('drop index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD');
   execute immediate('create index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_NEW on example_table ( id, another_field)');
end@`

Answer (score 0):

You must use another statement delimiter, if you want to use db2 compound statement.
In Squirrel: Session -> Session Properties -> SQL -> Statement Separator = @.
Indexes in Db2 are fully qualified by 2 `SYSCAT.INDEXES` columns: `INDSCHEMA` and `INDNAME`. So, it's advisable to use both these fields in a SELECT statement on SYSCAT.INDEXEX as in example.
You can't use static DDL statements in a compound statement. Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements instead.
Below is an example emulating `UPDATE INDEX` for the index in a schema equal to `CURRENT SCHEMA` special registry set in the session.

```
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT indname FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES WHERE INDSCHEMA = CURRENT SCHEMA AND INDNAME = 'TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD') 
THEN 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX TEST_CREATE_INDEX_OLD';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'
    create index TEST_CREATE_INDEX_NEW on example_table
    (
        id,
        another_field
    )
    ';
END IF;
END
@
```